# How resolve Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs IAwaitable in F#

Tags: .net, f#, async-await, botframework

I need to implement the interface from Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs library that uses the interface IAwaitable like this:

```
member this.MessageReceivedAsync(context:IDialogContext, argument:IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>)=
```

I don't know how await the IAwaitable. The Async hasn't a helper for the IAwaitable so i don't know how to convert this to an IAsync<'t>.
The `!` operator does not work.

Answer (score 1):

There was a `.ToTask()`. It could help to run async.